# Implementar interface com listas ligadas

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, lista-encadeada

Boa noite pessoal,

Precisava de uma ajuda aqui. Estou a  começar a aprender a implementação de listas ligadas em java, mas nao consigo entender nem achar uma solução para isto.

Tenho esta interface:

```
public interface ISet<E> extends Iterable<E> {
/**
* Inserts another element in the set.
* @param x The element to be inserted
* @requires x!=null
*/
public void insert (E x);

/**
* Removes a given element from the set.
* @param x The element to be removed
* @requires x!=null
*/

public void remove (E x);

/**
* Returns an element of the set.
* @param i
* @return
* @requires 0 <= i < size()
*/
public E get(int i);

/**
* Returns true if the element is in the set and false otherwise.
* @param x The element
* @return if the element is in the set
* @requires x!=null
*/
public boolean isIn(E x);

/**
* Returns true if the set is empty and false otherwise.
* @return if the set is empty
*/
public boolean isEmpty();
/**
* Returns the cardinality of the set
* @return the number of elements in the set
*/
public int size();

/**
* Returns true if other is s subset of this and false otherwise.
* @param other The other set
* @return if the set is subset of this
*/
public boolean subSet(ISet<? extends E> other);

/**
* Returns a generator that produces all elements of the set,
* exactly once in arbitrary order
* @return an iterator of the elements in the set
* @requires this not be modified while the generator is used
*/
public Iterator<E> iterator();
}
```

E preciso de construir uma implementação para esta interface usando listas ligadas. Alguem me consegue ajudar?

Sei que preciso começar assim:

```
public class Set<E extends Iterable<E>> implements ISet<E>{
    private Node<E> head;
    private int size;

    public Set() {
        head=null;
        size=0;
    }
class Node<E extends Comparable<E>>{
        private E element;
        Node<E> next;

        public Node(E e) {
            element = e;
            next = null;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return element.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você não pode usar a lista ligada que já existe no Java pra implementar essa interface? Entendo o valor didático de fazer "na mão", mas se a ideia do exercício é aprender conjuntos, não tem muito sentido ter que fazer uma lista pra chegar lá.

Comment: Nao, tem de ser mesmo feito à mao

Comment: A classe que implementa sua interface tá muito estranha. Compreende o uso do generics em Java?

Comment: Sim compreendo.

Comment: Por quê o `extends Comparable<E>`?

Comment: `List` é uma coisa e `Set` é outra coisa. O código da interface se aproxima mais de um `Set` (conjunto sem repetições e possivelmente sem ordenação) enquanto que a descrição da sua pergunta fala em "*listas ligadas*" (ou seja, sequências ordenadas de elementos permitindo repetições). Qual é o que você quer? Estou tentando elaborar uma resposta, mas sem essa informação fica difícil.

Comment: Pois é, esse exercício me parece muito mal elaborado... Ele quer ensinar Conjuntos mas envolve a construção de listas. Não me parece certo.

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu quero a das listas ligadas, mas usando essa interface